# Make the emacs command history size unlimited so I can keep track of files?

Tags: buffers, files, history

I'd like to make the size of the emacs command history unlimited.  I open and edit too many files in many different folders and I need a way to keep track of them.  The emacs command history looks like a good place to do that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a *command history* proper, but there's a *minibuffer history*.  The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html#Minibuffer-History) says the following about it:

> Every argument that you enter with the minibuffer is saved in a
>   “minibuffer history list” so you can easily use it again later.

then

> Emacs keeps separate history lists for several different kinds of
>   arguments.  For example, there is a list for file names, used by all the
>   commands that read file names.  Other history lists include buffer
>   names, command names (used by ‘M-x’), and command arguments (used by
>   commands like ‘query-replace’).

The file of file names is what you want.  About the length of these lists:

> The variable ‘history-length’ specifies the maximum length of a
>   minibuffer history list; adding a new element deletes the oldest element
>   if the list gets too long.  If the value is ‘t’, there is no maximum
>   length.

So you can achieve that by adding the following line in you init file:

```el
(setq history-length t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original post sounds like
an
[*XY* problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):
you want to keep track of lots of buffers and files (the real
issue), and you wonder if the command history would be a good way
to do that.

Depending on your needs (hard to tell from the original post), try using:

- [`ibuffer`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) to
  manage your buffers and files.
- [`projectile`](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) to manage
  your projects.
- [`ibuffer-projectile`](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-projectile) to integrate `ibuffer` and `projectile`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The need should be evident: Keeping history of all files I've opened in Emacs. Emacs seems to have a limit on that, which is 10 items or so, which was way too low for me. (setq history-length t) solved the issue. Thanks.